# Vertical slides in ionic 2

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, slider

I am using ionic 2, i would like to have vertical slides, had tried to implement using swiper and also tried passing the {direction : vertical} in options(directive) of ion-slides( which worked in ionic 1.x) but nothing worked is there any alternative solution ?

HTML :

```
<ion-slides pager options="options" style="background-color:white;">

   <ion-slide> 
     <h2>Slide 1</h2>
   </ion-slide>

   <ion-slide>
     <h2>Slide 2</h2>
   </ion-slide>

   <ion-slide>
     <h2>Slide 3</h2>
   </ion-slide>

</ion-slides>
```

JS :

```
export class HomePage {
   constructor() {
      this.options = {
         direction: 'vertical'
      };
   }
}
```

Comment: Add some code here so we can help you..

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa , added the code, can u check it!

Comment: This is now working with the latest Ionic 2 release: beta.1

Comment: @brandyshea i am currently using ionic 2-beta.17, but isn't working

Comment: beta.17 is referring to the CLI version, some docs on the differences here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/using-npm/.

Please run `ionic info` from _within_ the project folder to see the `Ionic Version`. Changelog for beta.1: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/2.0/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta1-2016-02-18

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `direction="vertical"` properties:

```
<ion-slides pager direction="vertical">

  <ion-slide>
      //Your html
  </ion-slide>

 </ion-slides>
```